# PHP:keep multiple checkbox checked in php after refresh when name is in array

Tags: php

i have problem with checkboxes value.I am getting values in array.Everything is fine But when i refresh the page then checked box becomes unchecked..
The code is:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($ptype as $pvalue) { $i++;?>
          <div style="margin:0px 10px 0 10px; float:left; color:#000000;">
            <input type="checkbox"  class="check" name="prop_type[]"  id="pro1"  value="<?= $pvalue['id'] ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['prop_type'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>> 
            <?=str_replace("_"," ",$pvalue['type'])?>
          </div>
          <?php }?>
```

I am using codeingnator and getting $pvalue from controller..can sombody elp me regardin this :(

Comment: Your checking to see if 'prop_type' exists in post at all and then setting everything to checked=checked?

Comment: yes this is set and when i change my code to <?= $pvalue['id']='23' to particular id then the checkbox checked but its not a solution (

Comment: Are you posting the page or not?

Comment: Like what @Mike B said, $_POST['prop_type'] doesn't exist after you refreshed the page. You need to find out what's causing it.